# Chart with Time axis only displaying first grid line and tick label (unitStepSize)

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to display a simple line chart of temperatures versus time. The dataset has temperatures and times in ten minute intervals. Times are in HH:mm format.
The graph is displaying correctly but only the left axis, right axis and first tick time value and grid line are displaying.

My data looks like this:

    `12:00 20.1
    12:10 20.3
    12:20 20.5
    ...
    13:20 21
    13:30 21.4`

I get the left axis labelled as 12:00 then one label at 12:10 with grid line, and then nothing until 13:30 on the right axis.

If I leave out the unitStepSize I get ticks and gridlines every minute (crowded). So obviously I am missing something to do with this parameter.

[image: Chart with missing grid lines]

```
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx,
    {
      type: 'line',
      data: data,
      options :
      {
        responsive:false,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales:
        {
          xAxes: [
            {
              type: 'time',

              scaleLabel:
              {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'Time'
              },
              time:
              {
                unit: 'minute',
                unitStepSize: '10',
                format: "HH:mm",
                displayFormats:
                {
                  minute: 'HH:mm',
                  hour: 'HH:mm'
                }
              }
            }],
          yAxes: [
            {
              scaleLabel:
              {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'Temp'
              },
               ticks: {
                max: 25,
                min: 15,
                stepSize: 1
            }

            }]
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are currently facing is causing because, you are passing the `unitStepSize` value as a *string*.

It should be a *number*, with no quotes (`''`) around it.

---

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector('#canvas').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ['12:00', '12:10', '12:20', '13:20', '13:30'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Temperatures',
            data: [20, 21, 22, 21, 23],
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(75,192,192, 0.4)',
            borderColor: '#4bc0c0',
            pointBackgroundColor: 'black',
            tension: 0,
            fill: false
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Time'
                },
                time: {
                    unit: 'minute',
                    unitStepSize: 10,
                    format: "HH:mm",
                    displayFormats: {
                        minute: 'HH:mm',
                        hour: 'HH:mm'
                    }
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Temp'
                },
                ticks: {
                    max: 25,
                    min: 15,
                    stepSize: 1
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Works like a charm.  Thanks. I may never have spotted that. Curious how it gave me the first grid line?

Comment: Sorry - too late at night!